# effect of coupling in MIMO systems

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, matlab, transfer-function, systems-engineering

I have a MIMO system with a 2x2 transfer matrix, for example consider:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{s+1} & \frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}\\ 
 \frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}&\frac{2}{s+2} 
\end{pmatrix}$

I would like to know how to characterize the influence that each channel has on another channel using Matlab.

So I would like characterize the effect of the coupling between the channels.

I know that to see how much a channel influences another i could use RGA, but is there also a way to see this by looking at the step responses and the magnitudes of the frequency responses?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Have you just *tried* looking at the response of each output channel to a step on each input channel?  It should be quick and easy-peasy if you've got the control systems toolbox.

Comment: Do you have the Control Toolbox?